# Array text sequence has gap

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a simple array text sequence that works, but I cannot figure out how to get A, B, and C to show for `2500` and then cycle back through. As of now, there is a blank frame that shows for `2500`.

Anyone know how I can get rid of that blank sequence?

```js
$('#cover1-seq1').show();
 var arr = $(".cover1-seq");
 var arrLen = arr.length;
 var i = 0;

 setInterval(function(){
  $(".cover1-seq").hide();
  $(arr[i]).show();
  i === arrLen ? i = 0 : i++;
 }, 2500);
```

```css
.cover1-seq {
 display: none;
}
.cover1-title {
 font-size: 6rem;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.cover1-description {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 3.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home-cover1-wrap">
    <div class="total-center cover1-seq" id="cover1-seq1">
     <h1 class="cover1-title">A</h1>
     <p class="cover1-description">A description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="total-center cover1-seq">
     <h1 class="cover1-title">B</h1>
     <p class="cover1-description">B description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="total-center cover1-seq">
     <h1 class="cover1-title">C</h1>
     <p class="cover1-description">C description</p>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Just use `i === arrLen - 1` instead of `i === arrLen`.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes So simple. Thanks! Feel free to leave an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your code using the modulo `%` operator and the jQuery `$.eq()` function this way:

```js
var arr = $('.cover1-seq'); //.show();
var arrLen = arr.length;
var i = 0;

var loop = function() {
    var item = arr.eq(i);
    var description = item.find('.cover1-description');

    arr.hide();
    description.hide();

    item.show();
    description.fadeIn(2000);

    i = (i + 1) % arrLen;
};

loop();
setInterval(loop, 2500);
```

```css
.cover1-seq {
    display: none;
}
.cover1-title {
    font-size: 6rem;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.cover1-description {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 3.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home-cover1-wrap">
    <div class="total-center cover1-seq" id="cover1-seq1">
        <h1 class="cover1-title">A</h1>
        <p class="cover1-description">A description</p>
    </div>
 <div class="total-center cover1-seq">
        <h1 class="cover1-title">B</h1>
        <p class="cover1-description">B description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="total-center cover1-seq">
        <h1 class="cover1-title">C</h1>
        <p class="cover1-description">C description</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How could I get the sequence to start right away, rather than there being the `2500` delay in the beginning? This is sort of the same thing as my initial question, except now in the front end. I am wanting to do it without doing `$('#cover1-seq1').show();` ... any ideas?

Comment: @Paul. Save the function in a variable, then call it once before the setInterval declaration. Check the updated answer :)

Comment: Thanks! If I wanted the description to `fadeIn` after the parent cover, could I just modify the description css, to `opacity:0` and then after ` arr.eq(i % arrLen).show();` add on `addClass('example`)` or would that apply to all the descriptions in the array?

Comment: The jQuery `$.eq()` function returns the desired element by index, you can save it in a variable, I will demonstrate

Comment: I updated my answer to use another variable `item` which holds the current element at `i % arrLen`.

Comment: Thanks, but I am referring to a certain part of the main element. Not just the `cover1-sec`, but the descriptions inside of it to fadeIn after the parent, `cover1-seq` does.

Comment: I updated my answer to do a fadeIn effect in the description.

Comment: Since your current needs is growing out of the scope of this question, I recommend asking a new one... Also, I think you may like a jQuery plugin I created while ago to animate phrases, look [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/ncs3uagj/) or check [the github page](https://github.com/WashingtonGuedes/jquery-bubble-text).

Comment: Thanks for all of your help! You did not need to provide the code, but I appreciate that you did. Have a great day!